# oracle sql, counting working hours

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have been trying to find something related but couldn't.
I have an issue that i need to produce an availability percentage of something. I have a table that includes events that are happening, which i managed to count them by the day they are happening, but i am finding issues to count the total number of working hours in a quarter or a year.

when each day of the week has a different weight.

Basically my question is: can i do it without making a table with all dates in that month/year?

An example of the data:

```
ID     DATE       duration   Environment
1     23/10/15       25          a
2     15/01/15       50          b
3     01/01/15       43          c
8     05/06/14       7           b
```

It can work for me by a calculated field or just a general query to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't really understand the question but if you want to generate dates using connect by level is an easy way to do it (you could also use the model clause or recursive with)  I did it here for just 10 days but you get the idea. I put in your dates as t1 and generated a list of dates (t) and then did a left outer join to put them together.

```
 WITH t AS
  (SELECT to_date('01-01-2015', 'mm-dd-yyyy') + level - 1 AS dt,
    NULL                                                  AS duration
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level < = 10
  ),
  t1 AS
  (
  SELECT to_date('10/01/15', 'dd-mm-yy') as dt, 50 as duration FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('01/01/15', 'dd-mm-yy'), 43 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('06/01/15', 'dd-mm-yy'), 43 FROM dual
  )
SELECT t.dt,
  NVL(NVL(t1.duration, t.duration),0) duration
FROM t,
  t1
WHERE t.dt = t1.dt(+)
ORDER BY dt
```

results

```
DT                     Duration
01-JAN-15               43
02-JAN-15               0
03-JAN-15               0
04-JAN-15               0
05-JAN-15               0
06-JAN-15               43
07-JAN-15               0
08-JAN-15               0
09-JAN-15               0
10-JAN-15               50
```

Comment: i wanted to sum working hours in a quarter or year, when i have 3 groups of working hours duration. you gave me the first piece of the answer, when i get to the second i will post it.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was my intention, and the full answer below.

```
 WITH t AS
 (SELECT to_date('01-01-2015', 'mm-dd-yyyy') + level - 1 AS dt

 FROM dual
   CONNECT BY level < =365
 ),
t1  as
(

SELECT  dt, 
CASE
                    WHEN (to_char(TO_DATE( t.dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DY') in ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI'))
                                    THEN  14*60
                    WHEN (to_char(TO_DATE( t.dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DY') in ('SAT'))
                                     THEN  8*60
                   WHEN (to_char(TO_DATE( t.dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DY') in ('SUN'))
                              THEN  10*60
                    ELSE 0  END duration ,
to_char(t.dt,'Q') as quarter
FROM t
)                             
select  to_char(t1.dt,'yyyy'), to_char(t1.dt,'Q'),sum(t1.duration)
from t1
group by 
to_char(t1.dt,'yyyy'), to_char(t1.dt,'Q');
```